# Exception in Activiti BPMN, java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: orthConnector

Tags: activiti, bpmn

I'm new to activiti and creating bpmn model using BpmnModel library
(activiti 6.0.0, java 1.8)
i got an error while executing below line

**new BpmnAutoLayout(model).execute();**

Here is the error message

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: orthConnector

```
at org.activiti.bpmn.BpmnAutoLayout.handleSequenceFlow(BpmnAutoLayout.java:271)
at org.activiti.bpmn.BpmnAutoLayout.layout(BpmnAutoLayout.java:158)
at org.activiti.bpmn.BpmnAutoLayout.execute(BpmnAutoLayout.java:99)
at my.com.scicom.esd.workflowservice.integrate.WorkflowNavigationTest.testDeployWorkflow(WorkflowNavigationTest.java:90)
at org.activiti.engine.test.ActivitiRule$1.evaluate(ActivitiRule.java:116)
```

please help anyone familiar with Activiti

Thanks in advance.